# Is there a way to know when a certain UITextView has been entered?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextview

I have two UITextViews! The problem i have is that I want an action to be performed when one of the textViews is entered and not the other! I placed the action code in

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

But the action is performed when either text view is entered. Is there a method that informs when a certain text view is being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two ways

first

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ( textView == YourTextView ) 
    {
            // ----- do here 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Second is

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
{
    if ( yourTextView.tag == yourTag) 
    {
            // ----- do here 
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You should explain that your first approach needs a retained reference to the textView. Additionally, the brackets ([textView == YourTextView]) are wrong in both examples.

Comment: Worked like a charm...the first answer

Comment: @tilo, if the textView is created in IB or a storyboard, you don't need a retained reference if you are using ARC; a weak one will do.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `tag` of your `UITextView` to differentiate them.

```
// Somewhere in your code
UITextView *firstTextView = // set up your text view
firstTextView.tag = 0;

- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
    // ...
    if (textView.tag == 0) {
        // firstTextView
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Its for this purpose itself textView is passed as an argument to the delegate function

```
- (BOOL)textViewShouldBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
```

You can maintain properties for the textview instances and within the delegate call just check which of the textview received the touch.